# What will be the next backend for machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, mxnet-format

Apache MXNet has been the choice of Mathematica Neural Network backend, but it has long since been mostly ignored by the ML community and now is finally in the attic (https://attic.apache.org/projects/mxnet.html). Will Mathematica switch to some other backends in the future?

Comment: I don't think we can know this, so I am voting to close this question. You may look the Live CEOing videos where Mathematica developers discuss upcming features and changes.

Comment: Don't close this please. There are top WRI devs on this site that can answer.